# how to set maximum depth on fixed position element in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my html code, I have a table like this

```
|-------|
|-------|
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   |   |
|-------|
```

The bottom left cell, is a fixed position so it move up and down when you scroll the page. It is basically a menu for the content on the bottom right cell. The top cell is the main menu.

As well, the whole page has a footer, that's always stuck to the bottom of the page. This is something I can't modify since I can only add my html to an existing page and not modify other stuff which includes that footer.

The issue is that when I scroll to the bottom of the page, my fixed position menu, overlaps the bottom page footer.

Is there a way I make it so that the bottom part of the menu will not go past the bottom of the right cell. Thus making the menu never overlap with the footer.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the [Z-Index](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)?

Comment: No, I just want the bottom part of the fixed position cell, to not go past the bottom part of the table. Basically setting a maximum y-coordinate to it.

Comment: I think you need to do that with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

it will be better if u show us your code or a jsfiddle...anyway my guess is::

you may try `position:fixed;bottom:10px;` in your fixed menu or `margin-top:10px` in your footer

you may also try `position:fixed;top:10px;` in your footer

but i cant assure you until you show us your code

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the footer you could set the bottom attribute of the fixed cell to that height and then it would never be below it.  Another option is to use javascript and do an on scroll event and if the scroll is at the bottom, then you set the bottom attr of the fixed position to the height of the footer.

```
.some-fixed-cell{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px; // This should be the height of the footer.
    // It will make it to where the fixed element will always leave 50px between
       it and the bottom of the window.
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by this `bottom attribute of the fixed cell to that height`. Can you show some code please?